# in Elementary OS 6.1 how to configure Gmail?

Tags: settings, pantheon-mail

I find it very difficult to configure my gmail currently in 2022, how do I solve this?  since I don't even have two-step verification activated.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I deleted their mailbox and installed thunderbird mail. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step guide :

- Go to your google account (user icon upper right of chrome or google.com)
- Click "Manage Your Google Account"
- In your account settings click on Security tab
- Scroll down to "Signing in to Google" section
- Click "App Passwords"

  *You will have to login with your google password again, for security*
- Add a new app specific password for Elementary Mail.
- Then make sure you copy it to your clipboard

  *They will not show it to you again*

(?) You may also want to save it somewhere in your
password manager / list.

- Use this password when adding your gmail account in Elementary.